# How to run MySQL on Ceph?

Tags: mysql, filesystems, ceph

I want to run MySQL on Ceph, and I did the follow step to achieve my goal.

**(Method one)Using Ceph RBD interface:**

1. Install MySQL and Ceph
2. Deploy Ceph environment, create a Ceph pool and create Ceph RBD device based on Ceph pool
3. Mount XFS on RBD device
4. Change the MySQL data directory to the directory of  RBD device.

**(Method two)Using  CephFS interface:**

1. Install MySQL and Ceph
2. Deploy Ceph environment, create two Ceph pools and mount CephFS
3. Change the MySQL data directory to the directory of  CephFS.

And then I achieved the goal of running MySQL on Ceph. I didn’t modify any MySQL codes. Is it that simple ?

I read the librbd.h and libcephfs.h. If I modify the code of MySQL filesystem IO interface, is that any differences between the version of modifying the MySQL or not modifying the MySQL code ?

I thought this question a lot but didn’t figure it out. Hope getting some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? For high availability of your MySQL data? Maybe, better will be to make high-available MySQL cluster (Galera of PerconaDB)?